# Kotlin enum classes in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, enums

I would like to use this Kotiln code in Swift, but I don't know how to get the best and clean solution:

```
enum class ProType(val gCode: String, val cCode: String) {
    FUND("FN", "PP"),
    STOCK("VA", "")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be like this:

```
enum ProType {
    case fund
    case stock

    var gCode: String {
        switch self {
        case .fund:
            return "FN"
        case .stock:
            return "VA"
        }
    }

    var cCode: String {
        switch self {
        case .fund:
            return "PP"
        case .stock:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Technically @esemusa answer is right. But if you have more than ~5 values in enum, you end up with difficult to maintain giant switch statements *for every property*.

So for cases like that I prefer to do this:

```
struct ProTypeItem {
    var gCode: String
    var cCode: String
}

struct ProType {
    static let fund = ProTypeItem(gCode: "FN", cCode: "PP")
    static let stock = ProTypeItem(gCode: "VA", cCode: "")
}
```

And you use it simply as `ProType.stock`, `ProType.fund.gCode` etc

You can also make ProTypeItem Comparable, Equatable etc.