# How can I assign my enum cases mutable associated values in Swift?

Tags: swift

I need to assign my enum cases associated values in Swift, but I want each case to have its own mutable value that has to be initialized once, therefore using a computed property and then switching on self doesn't work.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case c1(data: MyStruct),
         c2(data: MyStruct),
         c3(data: MyStruct),
         c4(data: MyStruct),
         c5(data: MyStruct)
    
    init(self) {
        self.data = MyStruct()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a Struct that's a pair of the raw enum c1-c5 (no associated value) and a MyStruct

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use Swift enums like Java/Kotlin enums. That's not going to work. Use either answer from this question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270967/kotlin-enum-classes-in-swift/

Comment: @Shadowrun Well that works but then I feel like enum associated values don't have much use :( Thanks for the help anyway, what you said looks like the most sensible approach here. But maybe I can ask another question to you related to enums: is there any way I can get the associated value of an enum case in an ordinary assignment expression? What I want is something like this: let test = data where MyEnum.c1(let data)

Comment: Enums with associated values have loads of uses, but if all your enum cases have the same type and number of associated values, then what you've described just refactors out, using a bit of type algebra, into a pair, which is also more ergonomic wrt your second question about getting the associated value for any/each case